# how to edit cells on editable column and open detail dialog on row selection on non-editable columns of a primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatables, jsf-2.2

Using

```
<p:dataTable 
    id="myissues"
    value="{myIssuesController.myIssuesListModel.issueList}"
    var="issueElement"
    selection="#{issue}"
    selectionMode="single" 
    rowKey="#{issueElement.idIssue}"
>
```

along with:

```
<p:ajax 
    event="rowSelect" 
    listener="#{myIssuesController.onSelectOneRow}" 
    update=":issueDetail" 
    oncomplete="PF('issueDetail').show();"
/>
```

I can open a dialog when I select a row on my `dataTable`.

How can I add an editable column to my table that goes into edition mode instead of opening the detail dialog when I click on one of its cells?

My first idea is to simply make the column editable and execute an oncomplete function that checks if the column selected is editable:

If it is, it will let it go into edition mode; if not it will call `PF('issueDetail').show();` and show the detail dialog.

Only I don't know how to check if a particular column has been selected. How can I do that?

Should I do it like this or is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using [primefaces selection](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml).

Basically, I removed the `<p:ajax>` component and added an extra column with a magnifier icon and a row editor icon to open the detail dialog / edit the entry; which is a more intuitive and user friendly solution than using the row selection action. The extra column looks like this:

```
<p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
    <p:commandButton update=":issueDetail" 
         action="#{myIssuesController.onSelectOneRow}" 
         oncomplete="PF('issueDetail').show()" 
         icon="ui-icon-search" title="View" />
    <p:rowEditor />
</p:column>
```